# Find all constraints that are referenced by another constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

```
Meldung 3725, Ebene 16, Status 0, Zeile 327
The constraint 'UQ_users_email' is being referenced by table 'posts', foreign key constraint 'FK_posts_users'.
Meldung 3727, Ebene 16, Status 0, Zeile 327
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.
```

Besides parsing the error message, how can I get a list of all constraints that block the drop of a certain constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FK** depends on (blocks drop of) **PK**/**UQ** of referenced table, any kind of constraint blocks drop of column(s) it depends on. List of tables referencing target table can be listed by this query:

```
select
  object_schema_name(fk.fkeyid) + '.' + object_name(fk.fkeyid) as [REF_BY], 
  object_name(fk.constid) as [REF_NAME]
from sys.sysforeignkeys fk
inner join sys.sysconstraints cs on cs.constid = fk.constid
where fk.rkeyid = object_id('dbo.my_target_table_with_constraint_to_drop', 'u')
order by 1, 2
```

all these FKs will block drop of PK/UQ from target table

Comment: Join to sysconstraints is actually unnecessary. Remains from some other tries.